# What is this terminal called in my service panel?

Tags: electrical

only ground wires are terminated in here.  I'd like to buy another one for the other side of the panel but I'm not sure what this is called.
[image: terminal in my service panel]

Comment: What make and model is the panel in question?

Comment: It's a squareD panel, I'll have to look at the unit for a model number.  This terminal was installed by a [licensed] electrician a few months ago; it's "aftermarket".  He even drilled the hole to mount it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a terminal or lug.  It's not likely rated for multiple conductors.  What you probably want is a grounding bar.

[image]

Comment: Can drill holes to mount a grounding bar like this?  There are not any pre-drilled holes for this at the bottom of the panel.

Comment: @MichaelC - Yes, it's actually specified in the NEC 250.8(A)(5) or 250.8(A)(6) - you can use a machine screw and a nut, or if the metal is thick enough to make two thread impressions, drill and tap a hole, or use a self tapping screw.

Comment: @batsplatsterson -- for Code gauge boxes, you need 10-32 threading, BTW.

Comment: I ended up getting a grounding bar similar to the one in the photo and installing it in a pre-drilled hole in the service panel.  Thanks for the help.